# Open command absolute path error 22

Tags: python

I am trying to use the open command in Python:

```
open('C:\Users\Thomas Le\Downloads\rhetoricalprecis.odt')
```

But, the command returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
open('C:\Users\Thomas Le\Downloads\rhetoricalprecis.odt')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\ThomasLe\\Downloads\rhetoricalprecis.odt'
```

Is there anything I did wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\r` in `Downloads\rhetorical` is being interpreted as a carriage return character. You need to either escape your backslashes:

```
open('C:\\Users\\Thomas Le\\Downloads\\rhetoricalprecis.odt')
```

Or use a raw string:

```
open(r'C:\Users\Thomas Le\Downloads\rhetoricalprecis.odt')
```